# Can I multiply an entire column with a scalar in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]>

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("SPOILER_Monster_Hunt.csv"))
> df.columns = ["S/No", "Member_Name", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5"]
> #some modifications below
> df = df.drop(index=0)
> df = df.drop(columns='S/No')
> df = df.fillna(0)
>
>  #Adjusting points with monster levels
>
> df['L1'] = df['L1'] * 50
> df['L2'] = df['L2'] * 150
> df['L3'] = df['L3'] * 300
> df['L4'] = df['L4'] * 1000
> df['L5'] = df['L5'] * 2000
>
> df.head()
> # show the dataframe
> print(df)
> ```

> Now the problem here is that multiplication of a column with a scaler just multiplies the value in that column to appear multiple times for instance `df[L1] = df[L1]*50` will make values of L1 repeat 50 times in the entire column but what I want is to multiply each value in that column to be multiplied by 50.

[here is the link to dataset I am using](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kssr3zfj8ugyn5r/SPOILER_Monster_Hunt.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: instead of multiplying the column with given value it makes that column repeat all its values the specified number of times.
""" AND IF YOU ARE ASKING WHAT HAPPENS OVERALL """
this code is supposed to multiply the number of monsters killed with their point scores for instance level 1 monster has 50 score so if somebody has killed 3 monsters his score should be 150.

Comment: Are your elements lists somehow? If so, fix that. Normally, multiplying by a scalar does exactly what you want, and storing lists is just counter productive with pandas

Comment: that's not how pandas works. perhaps you don't have numeric data in your cells? please try to produce a [mre] and show us what the data you're working with looks like so we can help you debug

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]. You're not providing enough information to reproduce the issue as the question is currently written.

Comment: Sorry for the headache my question gave you. I was modifying the question but in the meanwhile, somebody was able to answer it and it solved my problem. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this could be that your column dtype is a string object instead of an numerical one.
In python, multiplying a string with a scalar 'n' just repeats the string 'n' times.

You can check the datatype of each column by calling the df.dtypes attribute.

You can convert your column datatype into the required type using:

```
#Read the dataframe from csv file.
df = pd.read_csv('location')
#Perform all the necessary edits and modifications.
df.columns = ["S/No", "Member_Name", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5"]
df = df.drop(index=0)
df = df.drop(columns='S/No')
df = df.fillna(0)

print(df.dypes) # This will display the datatype of each column in the dataframe.

#Editing the values based on monster level.
df['L1'] = df['L1'].astype(int)
df['L1'] = df['L1'] * 50
df['L2'] = df['L2'].astype(int)
df['L2'] = df['L2'] * 150
df['L3'] = df['L3'].astype(int)
df['L3'] = df['L3'] * 300
df['L4'] = df['L4'].astype(int)
df['L4'] = df['L4'] * 1000
df['L5'] = df['L5'].astype(int)
df['L5'] = df['L5'] * 2000

#display the top 5 rows of your dataframe
df.head()
```

Alternate solution for overall cleaner code

If there are multiple rows that you need to change the type of, you can create a function to do so and call it on the required rows using df.apply().

```
columns_to_int = ['L1','L2','L3','L4','L5']
for col in columns_to_int:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)

df['L1'] = df['L1'] * 50
df['L2'] = df['L2'] * 150
df['L3'] = df['L3'] * 300
df['L4'] = df['L4'] * 1000
df['L5'] = df['L5'] * 2000

df.head()
```

Hope this helped.